# How to determine noise power and SNR from extinction ratio?

Tags: power, noise, signal-to-noise

I have a pulse train signal with infinite extinction ratio (ER). I want to add a white gaussian noise to my signal to get ER=15 (dB). I know that ER=P1/P0, i.e., the power level with the light source on (p1) divided by the power level with the light source off (P0).
Can I say that my signal power is equivalent to P1 and my noise power equivalent to P0?  If yes, I can simply calculate the noise power.
Also, how can I obtain the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR)? Is in this case SNR and ER the same?

I do appreciate if someone could help me to understand these. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: With the light on you're receiving signal+noise amount of power. Ignorable for large SNR, an issue for only 15 dB ratio though.

Comment: Is the purpose of this to predict the BER by forcing a faster worse SNR?  Normally one use a DC level to define ER which reduces the SNR of the 0 bit by 15 dB in the Rx. using Rx noise..  This also prevents the lasing latency.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No, I just have a pulse train signal with infinite ER. I want to change its ER to be finite (15 dB foe example). I thought that I can do that by adding noise to the signal. To this end, I need to find noise power.

Comment: Isn't it the Noise Power in the Rx and dispersion and group delay error that matters most for SNR & BER, why add more to the Tx?? You can certainly mix a 2nd laser with white noise and attenuate to achieve Tx SNR=15 dB, but for what purpose?